# Vue JS V-for not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Apologies for the beginner question. I'm a beginner to Vue and have been struggling to understand why my `v-for` is not rendering any data. I can see the array in the Vue console in `data`, but, the table does not render.

See below for my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="t-head-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Year 1</th>
            <th>Year 2</th>
            <th>Year 3</th>
            <th>Year 4</th>
            <th>Year 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in transactions">
        <td>{{item.account_category}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue JS:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    transactions: []
  },
  mounted: function(){
      this.fetchTransactions()
  },
  methods:{
    fetchTransactions: function(){
      var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/scenarios/transactions'
      fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function(data){
        vm.transactions = data;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Just want to know what I'm doing wrong.

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the responses, my transactions data looks like this:

[image: data output in Vue console]

I will look into `computed` transactions too.

**EDIT 2:**
Thanks for the response, I figured out that it was the curly braces I used in the HTML. Since I'm using Django as the back-end, it got confused between jinja and vue I think. I've since changed Vue's default delimiter to square brackets and it now works.

Comment: Better use COMPUTED property from Vue.js. And trivial question you are sure to obtain `data` with the correct strucure (control it with a `console.log(data);` before `vm.transactions = data;`? And maybe use `this.transactions` instead of `vm.transactions`

Comment: If you add the output from `data`, I can show you how to use COMPUTED property from Vue.js (because I can't obtain your transactions data)

Comment: Oh and an other thing add after your `v-for="..."` a key, like `v-for="item in transactions" :key="item"`

Comment: :key is mandatory for v-for

Comment: `data` is a factory, it should return a function

Comment: [Your problem isn't reproducible from the code you've posted](https://jsfiddle.net/o957saLb/)

Answer (score 0):

In Vue, it is mandatory that you give a key while applying `v-for`

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="t-head-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Year 1</th>
            <th>Year 2</th>
            <th>Year 3</th>
            <th>Year 4</th>
            <th>Year 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, i) in transactions" :key="i">
        <td>{{item.account_category}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**VueJs**

```
methods:{
    fetchTransactions: function(){
      var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/scenarios/transactions'
      fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function(data){
        this.transactions = data;
      })
    }
  }
```